# Nginx: Do not redirect without trailing /

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have a problem where Nginx redirects me to the wrong url if there is no trailing / provided.

I have haproxy setup to delegate the requests between multiple servers.

**curl output:**

```
➜  ~  curl -i www.ordify.com/register
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Tue, 14 Aug 2012 08:10:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Location: http://www.ordify.com:4000/register/
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Nginx config:**

```
server {
    listen *:4000;
    server_name ordify.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/website-com.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    error_page 405 = $uri;

    location / {
      root   /home/website/en/;
      index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    if ($host != 'www.ordify.com' ) {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.ordify.com/$1  permanent;
    }
    rewrite /registrieren/ http://www.ordify.com/register/ permanent;
    rewrite /presse/ http://www.ordify.com/press/ permanent;

}
```

I have already tried using http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($host != 'www.ordify.com' ) {
    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.ordify.com/$1  permanent;
}
```

This is a ineffective way. See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

The right way is to define a separate server to catch all other domains. Server names may be defined using regular expressions. Try this:

```
server {
    listen      *:4000;
    server_name www.ordify.com;
    ...
}

server {
    listen      *:4000;
    server_name ~^(?!www)\.ordify\.com$;
    return      301 http://www.ordify.com$request_uri;
    ...
}
```

`?!www` - [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), means that match something not followed by `www`.

Comment: Does not answer question from OP about trailing slash rewrite.